# What is the optimized way to insert large number of records in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert some hundreds of thousands of records in SQL Server 2008 R2.
What would be the best approach to insert them in least amount of time?

Comment: Does "insert" mean that your application is generating thousands of `INSERT` statements, or does it mean that you want to import data from flat files or another source? You might find the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421(v=sql.100).aspx) on optimizing bulk import performance is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS will certainly do the job probably in the least time (if you need to do it on a regular basis then you can create a job to do it and then just run the job) on the other hand if its a one off then there is a wizard in SQL management studio. Or you can just craft an SQL insert query, however, turn off indexes on the insert (to) table and batch the insert into (arbitrarily) 10,000 records, then reenable your indexes (they will be rebuild and stats updated when yor reneable them)